# How to insert mm/dd/yyyy format dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, insert, format

I have following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS job_history 
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID decimal(6,0) NOT NULL,
    START_DATE date NOT NULL, 
    END_DATE date NOT NULL
        CHECK (END_DATE LIKE '--/--/----'), 
    JOB_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    DEPARTMENT_ID decimal(4,0) NOT NULL 
);
```

How am I suppose to write a query for inserting values for that `END_DATE`?

I've tried :

```
insert into job_history(end_date) values('10/10/2020');
```

and get this error:

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '10/10/2020' for column 'END_DATE' at row 1

```
insert into job_history(end_date) values(str_to_date('10/10/2020', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```

with the following error:

> ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'job_history_chk_1' is violated.

Comment: Internally, SQL databases store objects with the `date` type as a number, similar to unix time. Checking that they're stored in a particular format doesn't make sense.

Comment: how do you want to check you value ???

Comment: Wdym? Insert a value there so I see if the CHECK works or not :-? But that's what I'm saying that idk how to insert a value with this check condition ON.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this :

1. remove your check constraint.
2. insert into job_history(end_date) values(STR_TO_DATE('10,10,2020','%d,%m,%Y'));

for more information : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Comment: Problem is that the exercise demands to have that check command, but idk how to actually CHECK if it works.

Comment: Your check constraint is not good.